# How to import an existing bare git repository into Gitlab?

Tags: git, import, repository, gitlab

I import my bare git repository into Gitlab as described as [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/Import-existing-repositories-into-GitLab) , because it was not recognized as an git repository, but creates a 94K big 'empty' repo (the original is 2,8GB big):

```
$ bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Processing test.git
INFO: Sidekiq client using redis://localhost:6379 with options:namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
 * Created test (test.git)
Done!
```

As a workaround I replace the empty project folder (which was created by import trial) with my bare repo. Afterwards I tree to clone the repo from remote and get the following error:

```
$ git clone git@mydomain.com:...test.git
Cloning into 'test'
fatal: '...test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But the git user should have all rights which are needed. -Maybe I have something overlooked?

My System: RHEL6.3, Git 1.8.3.4, Gitlab5.3.

Does Gitlab need a normal repository (non-bare)? Or what could be my problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does Gitlab need a normal repository (non-bare)?

No, all repos managed by gitlab are bare repos.

You should see:

```
/home/git/repositories/user1/repo1.git
/home/git/repositories/user1/repo2.git
/home/git/repositories/greoup1/repo3.git
...
```

Make sure the rights  of your `test.git` folder (and bare repo files within it) are the same than the existing bare repos under `/home/git/repositories/`.

If the import doesn't work, then "replace the empty project folder (which was created by import trial) with my bare repo" should.

But: you need to make sure any hook which was in the empty bare repo created by GitLab (in `~git/repositories/arepo.git/hooks`) is copied over your full bare repo replacing the empty one (same path).
Check also what was in `~git/repositories/arepo.git/info` and `~git/repositories/arepo.git/config`

To debug, try first to clone the empty bare repo created by GitLab during the failed import.
Then replace it with your own, double-check the hooks and try again.

---

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238817/6309) by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451418/user2451418) and documented in GitLab "[Trouble Shooting Guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#could-not-read-from-remote-repository)", the correct ssh url is:

```
git@git.myserver.com:repositories/mygroup/proj1.git
```

with **`:repositories`** mentioned.

---

To import bare repos (as mentioned by [Sytse Sijbrandij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613240/sytse-sijbrandij) [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23388901/6309) and in [`raketasks/import.md`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md))

- copy your bare repos under git repos_path (see `config/gitlab.yml` `gitlab_shell -> repos_path`)
- run the command below

  ```
  bundle exec rake gitlab:import:repos RAILS_ENV=production
  ```

Comment: I have added my import error to my question, because I think the main problem is the import of my bare repo. The permissions I have checked several times and those are (drwxrws---.).

Comment: @user2451418 then your workaround should work... I have edited my answer with some more ideas to consider.

Comment: I think there are no hooks created:***post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... Gitlab / test ... repository is empty***. And the same with satellites. Also the problem does not disappear when i try to clone the empty repo from remote via ssh. But on the server cloning works fine.

Answer (score 13):

For the documentation of this feature see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md

Comment: Good Link. +1. i have included it in my selected answer for more visibility.

Comment: You will also want to consider: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/8140 : only put your to be imported repos under a namespace (user or group subdir).

Comment: I followed the instructions on the linked page and did not see my new project. Upon investigation it was because the project was internal and not visible to a user without admin privileges. Fixing the visibility fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

For me the location to copy the repository is - /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories

I copied my existing bare repository in above dir and ran >gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos it worked!!!

Comment: Doing this return the following error message : "Please specify an import path that contains the repositories".
What worked was following https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/import.md and escaping the `[` and `]` characters when using zsh.

Answer (score 3):

I have it! It was a missing directory in my ssh path. This issue was already tracked [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide).

Sorry, but the error messages were not so obviously. I hope this can help other Gitlab-beginners like me :)

Comment: specific link - https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#gitlab-shell