# import entire GitLab Cloud project to new GitLab instance

Tags: gitlab

I have some projects set up on [GitLab Cloud](https://www.gitlab.com/cloud/), complete with issues, wiki pages, etc.  I've recently set up an internally hosted gitlab instance.  I'd like to bring these projects over from GitLab Cloud to the internal GitLab instance.

Bringing over the git repos [seems easy enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359936/how-do-i-import-an-existing-git-project-into-gitlab) (change the remote and push), but I don't see how to bring over the wikis and issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it seems like [this isn't possible](http://blogdotgitlabdotcom.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/pricing-for-gitlab-com-announced-10-users-are-free-and-no-change-until-july/#comment-490).  (There's a GitLab Feedback for it [here](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4488044-add-import-export-functionality-for-projects).)

However, the project wiki's seem to be their own git repos, which you can see on the [Git Access](http://demo.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlabhq/wikis/git_access) tab.  While that doesn't solve issues/snippets, it gets you part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to transfer over issues as I have not had to do that yet, but passing over the wiki is not that difficult.

On your old gitlab instance you will notice two repositories for your project (let's pretend your wiki is oldproject), one will say something like oldproject.git and oldproject.wiki.git.

The general path to the repositories where you can see the names I am talking about (let's assume user-name is "myaccount") can be found here:

```
/home/git/repositories/myaccount/
```

or (if using the omnibus installer):

```
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/myaccount/
```

I presume you already know how to transfer over oldproject.git.  You do the exact same thing with the wiki, only you create a bundle file out of oldproject.wiki.git:

```
git clone http://gitlab-instance-ip/user-name/oldproject.wiki.git
cd oldproject.wiki
git bundle create oldproject-wiki.bundle --all
```

Now initialize your new project in gitlab...I presume you already know how to do that as you suggested in your question that you know how to import the files from your project over to the new instance without problem.  Now repeat for the wiki:

```
git clone http://new-gitlab-ip/user-name/newproject.wiki.git
cd newproject.wiki
git pull /path/to/oldproject-wiki.bundle
git push -u origin master
```

I had a very similar problem to yours where I didn't see that anything was actually "pushed".  When I went back to the gitlab project I noticed that it was in fact updated with the wiki.  See here if you think it will help: [Importing Gitlab Wiki to a new Gitlab Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491535/importing-gitlab-wiki-to-new-gitlab-instance)

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that I don't have shell access to the server, as its on "GitLab Cloud"

Comment: This may be a long shot, but have you tried mirroring the gitlab repository to a local machine and then effectively having local shell access to the the clone?  Just a thought, I know this can effectively be done with svn.  Of course, if it is simply a matter of having to re-create the issues and you can import the wiki and the gitlab repository, you should be well on your way to what you want working in your local environment.  This was a couple of months ago was it not?  What did you wind up doing that worked for you?  Inquiring minds would like to know.