# Migrate GitLab 6.72 Server to Gitlab 12.1.6 Server

Tags: git, gitlab

We used GitLab 6.7.2 server and now we've set up a new GitLab 12.1.6 Server. So I want to migrate only one Project from GitLab 6.7.2 to GitLab 12.1.6.
What the best way I can do?

Because the GitLab 6.7.2 were holding so many projects, so I can't upgrade it to the version 12.1.6 to use backup and restore function, all projects is private projects so I can't use the import url function from Gitlab 12.1.6 too.
I thought I can clone the project from old GilLab and push it to new GitLab but It seem not a good way, because I want to have Wiki, merge request history ... in new Gitlab.

```
Git clone [old GitLab]
Git fetch -a
Git pull --all

Git push --all [to new GitLab]
```

The best way I can do to migrate a project from Gitlab 6.7.2 to Gitlab 12.1.6

Comment: Create a new origin pointing to the new GitLab server's repository and push the codebase to that instead (assuming it's a different URL).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the information, then you'll need to update the instance or a copy of the instance to at least 11.1 so that the [project export/import versions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html#version-history) match, then export the project and import it into the new instance.

If that's not an option, there are a few things you can export/import, but won't cover everything:

- repo files (using git clone from old project and git push to new project)
- [issues using CSV export](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/csv_export.html)
- wiki using the wiki specific git remote. See this other [stackoverflow answer on migrate a GitLab wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491535/importing-gitlab-wiki-to-new-gitlab-instance)

Comment: Thank @Arty-chan. I've used Git clone --bare and Git push --mirror for above issues. Thank for your support.