# Push repository with all commits to gitlab server

Tags: gitlab

We have recently lost access to our gitlab VM so we are unable to access our repositories. Is there any way to push our local repositories with all of their commits to a new gitlab server? We understand there's no way to restore issues, todos, etc.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question explains: [Import an existing git project into GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359936/import-an-existing-git-project-into-gitlab)

Create the repository on gitlab, add the new remote gitlab to your local repo and push.

```
git remote add gitlab url-to-gitlab-repo
git push gitlab master -f
```