# Import a .repo in Git server

Tags: git, import, repository

Everything is in the title, there is my problem. I've been asked for my internship, to create a git server.

Once this done, he then asked me to import some existing Git repository into the actual server. Once he copied the folder, I discovered that the files where some .repo folder, and in it i had some other folders or documents : branches (folder), config (document), description (d), HEAD (d), hooks (f), info (f), objects (f), packed-refs (d), refs (f).
I was wondering if anybody had one idea on how I could import all that, and use all the old version of the old git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's a copy of previously used Git repository. When you create a server-side repo (or using `git init --bare`), you end up with a structure like that, where the folder contains the files and directories you mentioned.

When I do the following, I end up with a structure like that...

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
git init --bare
```

The `foo` folder now contains the following structure (`-`: file, `d`: directory):

```
- HEAD
- config
- description
d hooks
d info
d objects
d refs
```

This looks similar to what you have.

Depending on your Git server, you might be able to simply copy this into the server's file system where its projects are stored. The name `.repo` probably should be changed something like `project.git`.

Here's a similar question explaining a similar case for importing into GitLab: [How to import an existing bare git repository into Gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214363/how-to-import-an-existing-bare-git-repository-into-gitlab)

Comment: ok so i got it all good, i just did a mistake miself, and had an old exported file, it wasn't really a .repo, was just a missname, thanks for the fast answer, and sorry for the slow response, to get the file working in my git server, i just clone it in it, and it was all good for me : git clone foo.repo foo
This did work perfectly and my server is now just perfect for what I need it to do !!

Thanks again :)